# Histomorphism a la Mendler

Tags: haskell, recursion-schemes

Using a histomorphism (`histo`) from [*recursion-schemes*](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/recursion-schemes-5.0.3/docs/Data-Functor-Foldable.html) I can get the a list containing only the odd indexes from an initial list:

```
import Data.Functor.Foldable

odds :: [a] -> [a]
odds = histo $ \case
  Nil                           -> []
  Cons h (_ :< Nil)             -> [h]
  Cons h (_ :< Cons _ (t :< _)) -> h:t
```

How can get the same thing using `mhisto`?

```
nil      = Fix Nil
cons a b = Fix $ Cons a b
list = cons 1 $ cons 2 $ cons 3 $ nil

modds :: Fix (ListF a) -> [a]
modds = mhisto alg where
   alg _ _ Nil = []
   alg f g (Cons a b) = ?
```

Answer (score 4):

This is it:

```
modds :: Fix (ListF a) -> [a]
modds = mhisto alg
    where
    alg _ _ Nil = []
    alg odd pre (Cons a b) = a : case pre b of
        Nil -> []
        Cons _ b' -> odd b'
```

```
GHCi> list = cata embed [1..10] :: Fix (ListF Int)
GHCi> odds (cata embed list)
[1,3,5,7,9]
GHCi> modds list
[1,3,5,7,9]
```

`odd` folds the rest of the list, while `pre` digs the predecessor. Note how the availability of an `y -> f y` function in the Mendler algebra mirrors the introduction of `Cofree` in the ordinary histomorphism algebra (in which digging back can be done by reaching for the tail of the `Cofree` stream):

```
cata  :: Functor f => (f c -> c) -> Fix f -> c
histo :: Functor f => (f (Cofree f c) -> c) -> Fix f -> c

mcata  :: (forall y. (y -> c) -> f y -> c) -> Fix f -> c
mhisto :: (forall y. (y -> c) -> (y -> f y) -> f y -> c) -> Fix f -> c
```

For further reading on `mcata` and `mhisto`, see chapters 5 and 6 of [*Categorical programming with inductive and coinductive types*, by Varmo Vene](https://kodu.ut.ee/~varmo/papers/thesis.pdf).